# Other uses for espresso machines?

Tags: espresso-machine

I own a espresso machine and was wondering if there are any other beverages besides coffee which could be produced using it.

Of course, using the hot water tap to get hot water for tea is quite obvious. But what other things could be produced, especially using the sieve and the high pressure the machine offers?

Comment: Gaggia used to (may still do I don't know) sell tea pods that fit in the coffee holder and you pumped heated water through it exactly the same as you would ground coffee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may completely be abuse of the machine, but I saw someone clean stainless steel jewelry once in an ECM machine. They put the jewelry in a sealed portafilter basket and backflushed the machine with cleaning detergent.

It seemed to clean the jewelry pretty well, but I can't say if it would be very different from putting it in the dishwasher.

At the very least, it seems to be a way to kill two birds with one stone when backflushing your machine.